# tortoise svn checkout repository folder from Disk D:/ to Disk E :/ how to?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I recently installed a tortoise svn subversion. Now, using tortoise svn, how can I check out the "Repository" folder from Disk D:/Repository  to Disk E:/ ?

Comment: Are you asking to move your repo from D: to E: ? I think you can just move the folder the way you normally would.

Comment: re-tagged to remove PHP, MySQL and Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for checking out a working copy from a local repository is described in detail [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-wc). If this specific section does not make sense, then you may want to read the entire containing chapter.